# Transpose all chords in string with regex (java)

Tags: java, transpose, chord

I have a working C# chord-transpose function. I try to rewrite it into java, but it seems not valid for some reason. Maybe lambda is not supported in the java regex?

```
    private String transposeChord(String ChordRegel, Integer amount)
    {
        String[] scale = { "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B" };
        java.util.Map<String, String> normalizeMap = new java.util.HashMap<>();
        normalizeMap.put("Cb", "B");
        normalizeMap.put("Db", "C#");
        normalizeMap.put("Eb", "D#");
        normalizeMap.put("Fb", "E");
        normalizeMap.put("Gb", "F#");
        normalizeMap.put("Ab", "G#");
        normalizeMap.put("Bb", "A#");
        normalizeMap.put("E#", "F");
        normalizeMap.put("B#", "C");

        Pattern r = Pattern.compile("[CDEFGAB](b|#)?");
        Matcher match = r.matcher(ChordRegel);
        return ChordRegel.replaceAll("[CDEFGAB](b|#)?", match =>
        int i = (java.util.Arrays.asList(scale).indexOf(normalizeMap.containsKey(match.toString()) ? normalizeMap.get(match.toString()) : match.toString()) + amount) % scale.length;
        return scale[ i < 0 ? i + scale.length : i ];)
        ) ;
    }
```

This is the working C# version:

```
    private string transposeChord(string ChordRegel, int amount)
    {
        string[] scale = { "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B" };
        string[] scale2 = { "C", "Db", "D", "Eb", "E", "F", "Gb", "G", "Ab", "A", "Bb", "B" };
        var normalizeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "Cb", "B" }, { "Db", "C#" }, { "Eb", "D#" }, { "Fb", "E" }, { "Gb", "F#" }, { "Ab", "G#" }, { "Bb", "A#" }, { "E#", "F" }, { "B#", "C" } };
        var normalizeMap2 = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "C#", "Db" }, { "D#", "Eb" }, { "E#", "F" }, { "F#", "Gb" }, { "G#", "Ab" }, { "A#", "Bb" }, { "B#", "C" }, { "Fb", "E" } };
        return new Regex("[CDEFGAB](b|#)?").Replace(ChordRegel, match =>
        {
            int i = 0; string NewKey = "";
            if (Mollen.Checked == true)
            {
                i = (Array.IndexOf(scale2, normalizeMap2.ContainsKey(match.Value) ? normalizeMap2[match.Value] : match.Value) + amount) % scale2.Length;
                NewKey = scale2[i < 0 ? i + scale2.Length : i];
            }
            else
            {
                i = (Array.IndexOf(scale, normalizeMap.ContainsKey(match.Value) ? normalizeMap[match.Value] : match.Value) + amount) % scale.Length;
                NewKey = scale[i < 0 ? i + scale.Length : i];
            }
            return NewKey;
        });
    }
```

Comment: If there is an error message, please include it in your question. If there is no error, tell us some example input and what happened vs. what you expected to happen.

Comment: Java uses `->`, not `=>`

Comment: Correct, you can't supply a lambda as an argument to `replaceAll`.

Comment: You made a matcher but you don't seem to be using it for anything.

Comment: I'm very bad with java to be honest and messed the logic a bit up. just playing around. the working C# variant is now also in the question to see what needs to be done

Comment: @Sander as others have suggested please provide the stack trace of the error(s) which occur when you try to run your code, or else the incorrect (actual) and correct (expected) output :)

Comment: The answers so far helped me to get the code closer to a working one, it is a little bit hard when i'm used to C# and get to learn java and how functions work.

I will work to a version that is better than this


@jakub_d It is totally not my meaning to ask for the complete answer.
I cannot start the program jet due to some basic errors, not real useful error atm.

Comment: The bitching is meant to be helpful as well, it shows the pattern to solve problems by yourself: are there errors? read them and try to fix them; is it doing something unexpected? what did you expect?; do you have a specific gap in your knowledge? try to name it ("how do I use a regex matcher in java?"), maybe you can find it somewhere already answered...  I feel that by providing too perfect an answer we are doing a disservice to Sander :)

Answer (score 3):

For best performance, I'd do it like this in Java 11 (see Java 8 version at the end):

```
private static final String[] scale = { "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B" };
private static final Map<String, Integer> scaleIndex = new HashMap<>();
static {
    Map<String, String> normalizeMap = Map.of("Cb", "B", "Db", "C#", "Eb", "D#", "Fb", "E", "Gb", "F#", "Ab", "G#", "Bb", "A#", "E#", "F", "B#", "C");
    for (int i = 0; i < scale.length; i++)
        scaleIndex.put(scale[i], i);
    for (String s : normalizeMap.keySet())
        scaleIndex.put(s, scaleIndex.get(normalizeMap.get(s)));
}

private static String transposeChord(String chordRegel, int amount) {
    int normalizedAmount = (amount % scale.length + scale.length) % scale.length;
    return Pattern.compile("[CDEFGAB][b#]?").matcher(chordRegel).replaceAll(r ->
            scale[(scaleIndex.get(r.group()) + normalizedAmount) % scale.length]);
}
```

The building of the `scaleIndex` map is only done once, and the `normalizedAmount` is always 0-11.

*Test*

```
for (int i = -12; i <= 12; i++)
    System.out.printf("%3d: %s%n", i, transposeChord("CbCC#", i));
```

*Output*

```
-12: BCC#
-11: CC#D
-10: C#DD#
 -9: DD#E
 -8: D#EF
 -7: EFF#
 -6: FF#G
 -5: F#GG#
 -4: GG#A
 -3: G#AA#
 -2: AA#B
 -1: A#BC
  0: BCC#
  1: CC#D
  2: C#DD#
  3: DD#E
  4: D#EF
  5: EFF#
  6: FF#G
  7: F#GG#
  8: GG#A
  9: G#AA#
 10: AA#B
 11: A#BC
 12: BCC#
```

---

***UPDATE:*** Java 8 version, not using lambda:

```
private static final String[] scale = { "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B" };
private static final Map<String, Integer> scaleIndex = new HashMap<>();
static {
    String[] normalize = { "Cb", "B", "Db", "C#", "Eb", "D#", "Fb", "E", "Gb", "F#", "Ab", "G#", "Bb", "A#", "E#", "F", "B#", "C" };
    for (int i = 0; i < scale.length; i++)
        scaleIndex.put(scale[i], i);
    for (int i = 0; i < normalize.length; i += 2)
        scaleIndex.put(normalize[i], scaleIndex.get(normalize[i + 1]));
}

private static String transposeChord(String chordRegel, int amount) {
    int normalizedAmount = (amount % scale.length + scale.length) % scale.length;
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[CDEFGAB][b#]?").matcher(chordRegel);
    while (m.find())
        m.appendReplacement(buf, scale[(scaleIndex.get(m.group()) + normalizedAmount) % scale.length]);
    return m.appendTail(buf).toString();
}
```

Comment: I think this works from Java 9 upwards.  Kudos for actually answering the question, rather than just complaining about it.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Well, Java 9 and 10 are EOL already, so anyone who has progressed past Java 8 should be on Java 11. Since the code doesn't work for Java 8, I'd simply recommend Java 11. :-)

Comment: That is impressive in such short time!
In my compiler the of command after Map.**of** isn't recognised and also r.**group**   is this due the version of java? cannot seem to find the Java version I use in IntelliJ

Comment: @Sander Correct. [`Map.of(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-) wasn't added until Java 9. Same for [`Matcher.replaceAll​(Function<MatchResult,String> replacer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.Function-).

Comment: @Andreas Is there are alternative for java 8?

Comment: @Sander Create the map using `new HashMap`, then `put` the mappings.

Comment: @Andreas That part I had figured out already, the hard part is that not everything in the replaceAll function can be executed, cannot find an alternative for the (r.group)